# How to make an iPhone web app not appear in the browser

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

I noticed there are apps like Google Translate where, when I do "Add to Home Screen" and then open it, it runs on it's own instead of in a the mobile safari browser. How do I make an app like that?

Comment: i wonder if it is possible at all to make a iphone web app not appear in a browser..

Comment: I know it's really running using mobile safari. But all the fari controls are gone, including the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in the

```
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
```